# decommissioning a domain controller

Tags: windows, domain-controller

I am new to AD. We have a total of three domain controllers that are also DNS servers. Can I decommission the DC running Windows Server 2003 standard. Will the global catalog be replicated safely?

Comment: Before doing anything, verify that you've selected at least one other server (preferrably more) to be a GC, then examine AD event logs to verify that replication completed successfully.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313994 article on creating a global catalog server, for anyone who needs some guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Run dcdiag and check replication to ensure that your AD is healthy
2. Safely migrate all FSMO roles to other servers
3. Ensure that at least one other DC is also a GC
4. Run dcdiag and check replication to ensure that your AD is healthy again

Assuming you don't have any other applications on the DC, particularly non-AD-integrated DNS, you should be good to dcpromo that down.

Comment: +1 but still a VTC...sorry mate.